# To user a loader widget, how do I get loading start/end event with a asynchronus firebase(observable) request?

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire like this

```
constructor(private afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
   allRRs$  = this.afDb.list(`research_reports-published/`).valueChanges();
}
```

where allRRs$ is an observable and using it in template like this.

```
<li *ngFor="let rr of (allRRs$ | async)"></li>
```

whats the way to figure out when allRRs$ loading completed. so that I can use it to show a loder icon.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Firebase but can you `subscribe` or `then/catch` with `valueChanges()`.

Comment: Can you show example code, wheather to place it in `ngOnit()` or somewhere else, and `isLoading` variable to be an observable or not. You can assume I have a `<loader></loader>` component available ?

Comment: guess the most straight-forward workaround would be `<loader *ngIf="isLoading"></loader>`. Then initialize `isLoading: true`. I'm just not sure when to assign `isLoading` back to false when you get the items from the database. I'm not really familiar with Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be pretty simple

```
<loader *ngIf="(allRRs$ | async)"></loader>
<li *ngFor="let rr of (allRRs$ | async)"></li>
```